# Rounding a number to 2 decimal places fails

Tags: java

I have a nasty bug in an interest rate calculation: I have to round the answer to the nearest cent, but

```
interest = Math.round(interest * 100) / 100;
```

removes the entire decimal portion. `interest` is a `double` type. Why is this? The equivalent code works fine in C++.

Comment: The real bug is that you are using floating-point for money. Never do that. Use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I've had a look at the duplicate, but is it really that complicated to do a rounding?

Comment: Out of interest, what is your equivalent code in C++? We have ::floor and ::ceil, but not an "out of the box" German rounding function.

Comment: Yes, it really is that complicated. The issue is as I stated there. Floating-point numbers don't have decimal places. They have binary places. If you want decimal places, use a decimal radix, i.e. `BigDecimal`. My answer there contains a complete refutation of the `*100/100` trick. It does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's set aside the potentially greater issue of your using a binary floating point for a quantity that requires a precise decimal representation.

The Java bods broke with tradition and decided that `Math.round(interest * 100)` should return a `long`, rather than a `double`. (I imagine they did this since any `double` that is not an integer will be rounded to an integer that can fit into a `long` type). So the expression

```
Math.round(interest * 100) / 100
```

is evaluated in integer arithmetic, so any remainder is discarded. The clearest workaround in my opinion is to write

```
interest = Math.round(interest * 100) / 100.0;
```

which forces evaluation to take place in floating point.

Also note that the resultant underlying floating point value will, in general, have trailing non-zero digits past the 2nd decimal place even after this rounding has been applied: a `double` only gives you 15 decimal significant figures of precision.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped it was going to be something simple like that!

Comment: Pleasure. But do note the cautions in using `double` for money values.

Comment: It may force evaluation to take palce in floating-point, but it also fails to round the number to two decimal places.

Comment: @EJP: That is a **very, very** good point. I've made that clear.

Comment: `double` only gives you 15.9 decimal significant figures *in an integral value*. When fractions come into it, all those bets are off.